# "mean init" fails during admin user creation

Tags: mean-stack

I follow the basic installation tutorial on for the mean stack on OS X.
MongoDB is running and all dependencies are believed to be installed.

During init of my first app, the script fails when asking for the admin user password (it fails before I am allowed to input anything as my admin password):

```
$ mean init myApp

? What would you name your mean app? myApp
? The Mean project is currently in developer preview. To help improve the -
  quality of this product, we collect anonymized data on how the mean-cli is used -
  You may choose to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below prompt)
  or at any time in the future by running the following command:

  mean disable user-reporting

  Do you want to help us improve the mean network (Y/n)?  Y
? Please provide your email so we can create your first admin user: joe@doe.com
? Please provide your username so we can create your first admin user: admin
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: myApp
git clone  --depth 1  -bmaster https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git "myApp"
Cloning into 'myApp'...


##############################################################
#
#   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
#
#   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
#   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
#   DO NOT run this in production.
#
##############################################################

    DB connection successful!

Please provide password so we can create your first admin user
prompt: password:  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;      
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at processResults (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1581:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1619:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1157:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1890:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:439:20)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:201:13)
```

I am able to create users manually in the resulting app folder.
But the resulting application seems to be incomplete and I cannot start it.

```
$ mean user joe@doe.com --addRole admin; 
  Adding role `admin` to user `joe@doe.com`

##############################################################
#
#   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
#
#   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
#   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
#   DO NOT run this in production.
#
##############################################################

    DB connection successful!

successfully updated
```

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. mark

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mongo database.

http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: MongoDB is ofcourse installed. As I say, I can connect to and create users manually in this DB